# Respond.min.js works only in IE 8 emulation mode of IE 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, ie8-compatibility-mode, respond.js

respond.min.js works only on IE explorer 8 emulation in developer's mode of IE 11. On real IE 8 it just silently does not function while in IE Tester gives en error:" expected ';' ( char 2060)".The result is a broken CSS. The respond.min.js is installed without modifications on the server. The actual char № 2060 there is ";". The site is : poiskdetei.ru.

Any ideas?

here is the code of my header section:

```
<head>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?    
family=Open+Sans+Condensed:700&subset=latin,cyrillic-ext' rel='stylesheet' 
type='text/css'>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">

<?php echo ccr_favicon();?>

<?php if(!empty($heal_option['heal_custom_css'])) { ?>
<style>
    <?php echo esc_html($heal_option['heal_custom_css']); ?>
</style>
<?php } ?>

<?php wp_head(); ?>
<!--[if lt IE 9]> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/html5-shiv.min.js"></script>     
<script type="text/javascript" src="/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since IE 10 or 11 (I don't remember), IE ignores conditional comments, even in emulation mode. So you can downgrade to a previous IE version 9 or 10 and then emulate IE8, IE7.